# How to avoid usmStatsNotInTimeWindows (1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0)

Tags: java, snmp

My application gets data from a device using SNMPv3 with AuthPriv setting.

many times there is failure in communication.

When checked using wireshirk, many times, there is a reported error as below

> report 1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0

SNMP request has setting

> UserTarget.setRetries = 2
>
> UserTarget.setTimeout = 5000

Meaning of error I found as below

```
This is set when the engineTime specified is not within the timeWindow of agent. The engineTime is considered not within the timeWindow if any of the following is true.

1. If the agent's snmpEngineBoots value is equal to 2147483647.
2. If the request's snmpEngineBoots value differs from that of the agent.
3. If the difference between the SNMP request's snmpEngineTime and that of the agent is greater than 150.

This error is reported by the agent with its first varbind containing the OID ".1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0" and the value is a Counter giving the number of packets that have been dropped because of this error. (Example screenshot below)
```

How to avoid this issue.

Comment: Not in time window and rediscovery are natural parts of SNMP v3. Your manager side code should properly handle that.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. Does it mean that we cannot avoid "Not in time window" error. What kind of handling you are referring to. is it retrysetting or something else. Also many times EngineTime =0 and EngineBoot = 0 in request and other times there is value.

Comment: I cannot give you a Java example, but a C# one, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/blob/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpget/Program.cs#L213 Whenever a report message is received by SNMP manager, it should retry discovery to learn the right time window to use.